# Why does this code print 00? And what can i do to fix it?

Tags: c

So I was coding as a revision for my data structures class, so I decided to make an assignment for myself to familiarize myself with linked lists. For some reason, it prints 00. I have no idea why but this is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct op{

  char name[10];
  char origin[10];
  char ability[20];
  int speed;
  int pick;
  struct op* next;

}op;

void menu();
op* make_node(FILE* fp);
op* append(op* head, op* element);
op* fill_LL(FILE* fp,op* head);
void display_LL(op* head);


int main(void) {

  op* head;
  head=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op*));
  head->next=NULL;

  op* element;
  element=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op*));
  element->next=NULL;
  
  int o;
  o = 6;

  FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
  
  //printf("Heal me, Lord, and I will be healed; save me and I will be saved, for you are the one I praise.\n");
  append(head,element);
  //printf("\nAnd the people all tried to touch him, because power was coming from him and healing them all.\n");
  display_LL(head); 
  //printf("\nBut I will restore you to health and heal your wounds,' declares the Lord.\n");
  fclose(fp);

return 0;

}

//simple menu funtion

void menu(){

  printf("welcome to the R6S database \n");
  printf("Press 1 to get info about an operator");
  printf("Press 2 to display the whole database");
  printf("Press 3 to add a new operator");
  printf("Press 4 to change info about an operator");
  printf("Press 5 to sort operators by pick rate and display the ranking");
  printf("Press 6 to exit");

}


op* make_node(FILE* fp){

  op* element=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op*));

  char garbage[10];

    fgets(element->name,10,fp);
    fgets(element->origin,10,fp);
    fgets(element->ability,20,fp);
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&element->speed);
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&element->pick);
    fgets(garbage,10,fp);

return element;

}


op* append(op* head, op* element){

op* walker;
walker=head;

if(head==NULL){
head=element;
}

while (walker->next != NULL){
walker=walker->next;

}
walker->next = element;

return head;
}


op* fill_LL(FILE* fp,op* head){
  op* element;
  while(!feof(fp)){
    element=make_node(fp);
    head =append(head,element);
  }

  return head;
}



void display_LL (op* head){

op* walker;
walker = head;

while (walker->next!=NULL){

//Heal me, Lord, and I will be healed; save me and I will be saved, for you are the one I praise.

//And the people all tried to touch him, because power was coming from him and healing them all.

//But I will restore you to health and heal your wounds,' declares the Lord.

printf("%s", walker->name);
printf("%s", walker->origin);
printf("%s", walker->ability);
printf("%d", walker->speed);
printf("%d", walker->pick);

walker=walker->next;
}
}
```

Excuse the bible verses I thought this was actually cursed. I did at some point have a printf("00"); to test a function but i deleted it. It's like the ghost of this line of code keeps haunting me. I took it to different compilers and it shows me the same output which is just 00. Please help me.

Also this is the file that i read from:

```
Jaeger
German
AIDS
3
48
---
Mira
Spanish
Mirror
1
12
---
Ying
Chinese
Candela Flashbangs
2
10
---
Caveira
Brazilian
Silent step
3
50
---
Montagne 
French
Shield
1
29
---
```

Comment: In `display_LL`, `while (walker->next!=NULL){` should be `while (walker!=NULL){`, otherwise it doesn't print the contents of the final element. (I have no idea why it outputs `00`, but the code does not fill in any of the list elements, so it could be printing any old junk.)

Comment: yeah you are right i havent finished the code yet.

Comment: `head=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op*));` should be `head=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op));` but type casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary, so `head=malloc(sizeof(op));` is preferred, or better yet, `head=malloc(sizeof(*head);`. Similarly for `element=(op*)malloc(sizeof(op*));`.

Comment: The `00` output probably comes from `printf("%d", walker->speed);` and `printf("%d", walker->pick);` if the malloced memory happens to be initialized to all-zeros.

Comment: when i call the append function with ```append(head, make_node(fp))``` it prints the first three elements of the struct and then a segmentation fault. But the 00 is still at the beginning.

Comment: The `malloc` call in`make_node` is using the wrong size in the same way as the other `malloc` calls (should be `sizeof(op)`).

Comment: Also, `make_node` should set `element->next = NULL;`, or `append` should set `element->next = NULL;`, or both.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined Behaviour**: you're printing the values of objects without having assigned anything to them.

```
printf("%s", walker->name);    // garbage <empty string>
printf("%s", walker->origin);  // garbage <empty string>
printf("%s", walker->ability); // garbage <empty string>
printf("%d", walker->speed);   // garbage 0
printf("%d", walker->pick);    // garbage 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, there are no curses in your computer. Computers run on science and technology and mathematics, not holy spirits. Get that out of your mind. Sometimes they do strange things, but there is always a logical explanation.

Your code creates two nodes and does not set any values in the nodes. Then it prints the list of nodes it made. But it doesn't print the last one, because the last node's `next` is NULL. So it actually just prints the first node.

It seems that your first node just has zeroes in it. Usually, when you allocate some memory, it has random garbage data in it, left over from something before, but perhaps since this is the first thing your program allocates, you got all zeroes.

The name is blank. The origin is blank. The ability is blank. The speed is 0. The pick is 0. So, it prints 00.

Comment: "there are no curses in your computer"  Except for [new curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)! :)